# Video driver on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, amdgpu, gpu-driver

I'm kind of new to ubuntu and I'm having some problems with drivers for my gpu [RADEON RX 550].

when I first installed ubuntu it automatically set "Radeon RX 550 Series (POLARIS11, DRM 3.41.0, 5.13.0-19-generic, LLVM 12..." as the default driver. It happened that I tried to install the official AMD drivers but the process failed and after the reboot I'm stuck with
"llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.1, 128 bits)" driver wich disabled all the animations and made the system laggy.
Does anyone know how to at least get back the original one?
Let me know if you need further informations.

I have `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf` that contains `blacklist amdgpu`.

Comment: There are no  "official AMD drivers" that you could install. You probably blacklisted the driver.

Comment: Add output of `grep amdgpu /etc/modprobe.d/*` to the question.

Comment: here's what i got:
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf:blacklist amdgpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this file by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf
```

and reboot.

You installed wrong drivers that blacklisted the original one.