# AMD radeon RX6500 XT graphic card not working with 21.10

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, radeon, amdgpu

I have just bought an AMD Radeon RX6500 XT MSI graphic card, but can't make it work with my Ubuntu 21.10.

I thought that there were preinstalled open source drivers, and that it would be plug and play, but I'm stuck with a VGA display.

As suggested [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378030/video-driver-on-ubuntu-21-10), I checked that amdgpu is not blacklisted. It's not the case.

Installing the amdgpu driver only works on 20.04.2. I don't want to reinstall everything, especially that 22.04 is around the corner.

```
$ lspci 
...
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev c1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 743f (rev c1)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21 HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT]
...
```

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

EDIT: after executing `sudo update-pciids`, I now see this:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 24 [Radeon RX 6400 / 6500 XT] [1002:743f] (rev c1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now RX6500XT is works with the latest driver.

https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/21.50/ubuntu/focal/amdgpu-install_21.50.50000-1_all.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i amdgpu-install_21.50.50000-1_all.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl
```

[here is my desktop's screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX3B6.jpg)

Comment: I noticed it a few days ago. What a stress to have bought a card I could not use. Do you know if it will also work with Ubuntu 22.04LTS that has just been released ?